# How to compute the following limit? $\lim\limits_{x\to\ 0^+} {\frac{x-\lfloor x \rfloor}{x+\lfloor x \rfloor}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions, indeterminate-forms, fractional-part

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\ 0^+} {\frac{x-\lfloor x \rfloor}{x+\lfloor x \rfloor}}$$
Here, $\lfloor x \rfloor$ represents the floor of $x$.

I tried using a graphing calculator (desmos) to plot the function $f(x) = \frac{x-\lfloor x \rfloor}{x+\lfloor x \rfloor}$

from the graph (see image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSi0U.png)), it is clear that this limit is equal to 1. But is there any **analytical** way to compute this limit?

Comment: Floor *or* ceiling? Which is it?  As $x$ is small, positive and close to one we can just assume $[x] = 0$.  If you want to be formal:  For any $\epsilon > 0$ we can let $\delta = \frac 12$.  Then if $0 < x < \frac 12$ then $|1-\frac{x-[x]}{x+[x]}| = 0 < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $0<x<1$, you have that $\lfloor x\rfloor =0$. Hence
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to\ 0^+} {\frac{x-\lfloor x \rfloor}{x+\lfloor x \rfloor}}
=\lim\limits_{x\to\ 0^+} \frac{x}{x}=1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

From the graph, it's not only clear that the limit is $1$, it can also be seen that on the interval $[0,1)$, the vaue of $f(x)$ is equal to $1$. This can easily be shown analytically, since for $x\in[0,1)$, you have $\lfloor x\rfloor = 0$.